# Is there an IC that will output randomly?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, random-number

Recently I've started collecting those tiny arcades boxes, and found some information to wire them so they stay on the demo mode. This way they can be used as a decoration. Here's an example vid of what I'm going to do: https://youtu.be/kea0oIe023I. [image: tiny arcade]

Instead of having it run in demo mode though I want to have the two buttons and little joystick get random inputs. So far I haven't been able to find any little chip to accomplish this with. My idea would be to find a chip with 6 or so pins that output signals randomly, one pin at a time. Is this something I can find?

Comment: I doubt random movements of the stick and buttons would lead to any kind of useful gameplay. Try it yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are chips that can do what you need. They are called MCU -microcontrollers. Get any cheap MCU, and program it with few Linear Feedback Shift Registers, LFSR, [see examples here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4400).

Comment: Yes Ale.. but No you cannot "find it" already programmed.  This is a simple buy search question.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75, we will go too far if we will expand all questions too literally. Should we consider that the chip miust be soldered? Has power supplies? Connectors? OP asks to "find any little chip to accomplish this with". So the answer is yes, "with a MCU" you can accomplish this task, "with". So my answer is formally correct.

Comment: "Is this something (he) can find?" ought to give you some clues

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Ale..chenski, Thanks for the help! I ended up using the Adafruit Trinket. It's small to fit inside the arcade box, can power it, and has 5 GPIO pins, just the amount I needed for this project. I'm really happy with the results!

Answer (score 0):

Not an IC but available in a module that is the size of a 600mil wide DIP and has pins you can plug into a breadboard or perf board - you can use the [random()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/) function on an [Arduino](http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Arduino-Nano-Pin-Description-952x1024.jpg). For example, random(0, 101) will generate a number between 0 and 100 inclusive.

It's basically an 8-bit microcontroller and support components with a freely available development environment and bootloader/USB interface all for a few dollars each.

Answer (score -1):

No there is no simple chip that can you can buy to do what you want.

It requires a design with specs.  This is a fundamental flaw by every new designer.
To encourage a solution, establishing the power, analog and logic behavior, skill limitations and design effort may be interesting but it is not a solution.

For example may be that someone with basic skills in CMOS could simulate or breadboard a solution in 1 afternoon while someone who has never used a uC might take weeks or never to figure out how to program, compile and get it to work.

All because the requirements were not completed.